# Allocate shared variables in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

How to allocate shared variables in CUDA? I have a kernel where data needs to be shared across threads belonging to a particular block. I need two shared variables named `sid` and `eid`. I use it like this:

```
extern __shared__ int sid, eid
```

but it is giving me an error that `__shared__` variables cannot have external linkage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [allocating shared memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531247/allocating-shared-memory)

Answer (score 9):

There are  two ways to allocate shared memory : static and dynamic

**1、static**

```
  __shared__ int Var1[10]
```

**2、dynamic** : should add "extern" keyword

```
extern __shared__ int Var1[]
```

If you use dynamic way to allocate shared memory, you should set the shared memory size when you call the function. for example:
`testKernel <<< grid, threads, size>>>(...)`
the third parameter is the size of shared memory. In this way, all the shared memories start from the same address. If you want to define several shared memory variables, you should write code like following.

```
__global__ void func(...)
{
    extern __shared__ char array[];
    short * array0 = (short*)array;
    float * array1 = (float*)(&array0[128]);
}
```

Comment: Now if this function is __device__ function and i'm calling it from some __global__ function then how to achieve this thing?

Comment: you can pass the shared memory adress to the  device function

Comment: @Samuel if you declare your shared memory outside the global function, it should be visible in by other __device__ functions in the file, no ?

Comment: I think the ansower is yes.You can write a testbed to test it. I think it's not good to declare shared memory outside the global function

Comment: How is this possible to have ```float** array``` instead of ```float* array0``` and ```float* array1```? In this case the storage of ```float**``` should also be assigned dynamically.