# cuda Parallel reduction #6 works and reduction #7 fails

Tags: cuda, gpu, reduce

Im using this code for reduction:

http://www.math.nsysu.edu.tw/~lam/MPI/code/cuda/reduction.cu

that is based on Mark Harris talk as in here

http://www.math.nsysu.edu.tw/~lam/MPI/lecture/reduction.pdf

But for

```
#define blocksize 1024
#define gridsize  1024*8
#define size blocksize*gridsize
```

Kernel reduce6 works and reduce7 fails. Is it bcos reduce7 is dependant on amount of shared memory that size has to reach even "size" defined above?

Code snippet is here:

```
#define THR_PER_BLC 1024
#define BLC_PER_GRD  16
#define GRID_SIZE THR_PER_BLC * BLC_PER_GRD

template<unsigned int nThreads>
__global__ void reduce7(int *g_idata, int *g_odata, unsigned int n) {
     //I added GRID_SIZE myself so it can be volatile
     __shared__ volatile  int sdata[THR_PER_BLC]; 
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * (nThreads * 2) + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int gridSize = nThreads * 2 * gridDim.x;
    sdata[tid] = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i + nThreads];
        i += gridSize;
    }
    __syncthreads();
// reduction in shared memory
    if (nThreads >= 512) {
        if (tid < 256) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 256]; }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (nThreads >= 256) {
        if (tid < 128) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 128]; }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (nThreads >= 128) {
        if (tid < 64) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 64]; }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (tid < 32) {
        if (nThreads >= 64) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32];
        if (nThreads >= 32) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16];
        if (nThreads >= 16) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 8];
        if (nThreads >= 8) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 4];
        if (nThreads >= 4) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 2];
        if (nThreads >= 2) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 1];
// transfer of the result to global memory
        if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
    }
}
```

And this kernel is called like this from main:

```
threads = THR_PER_BLC /2 ;

int gsize = BLC_PER_GRD /8;

switch (threads) {
    case 512:
        reduce7<512> << < gsize, threads >> > (g_idata, g_odata, GRID_SIZE);
        break;
    case 256:
        reduce7<256> << < gsize, threads >> > (g_idata, g_odata, GRID_SIZE);
        break;
    case 128:
        reduce7<128> << < gsize, threads >> > (g_idata, g_odata, GRID_SIZE);
        break;
    case 64:
        reduce7<64> << < gsize, threads  >> > (g_idata, g_odata, GRID_SIZE);
        break;
    case 32:
        reduce7<32> << < gsize, threads  >> > (g_idata, g_odata, GRID_SIZE);
        break;
    case 16:
        reduce7<16> << < gsize, threads >> > (g_idata, g_odata, GRID_SIZE);
        break;
    case 8:
        reduce7<8> << < gsize, threads >> > (g_idata, g_odata, GRID_SIZE);
        break;
    case 4:
        reduce7<4> << < gsize, threads >> > (g_idata, g_odata, GRID_SIZE);
        break;
    case 2:
        reduce7<2> << < gsize, threads >> > (g_idata, g_odata, GRID_SIZE);
        break;
    case 1:
        reduce7<1> << < gsize, threads >> > (g_idata, g_odata, GRID_SIZE);
        break;
}
cudaThreadSynchronize();
```

Is basically means that reduce7 cant be called with to big GRID_SIZE?

This are my tests

```
#################################################################
6 Unroll the complete loop
Kernal elapsed time =      0.030(ms)
Elapsed time =      0.057(ms)
Sum = 8192, with BLC_PER_GRD 16 THR_PER_BLC 512
#################################################################
7 Final
Kernal elapsed time =      0.015(ms), band =
Elapsed time =      0.040(ms)
Sum = 8192, with BLC_PER_GRD 16 THR_PER_BLC 512
#################################################################

#################################################################
6 Unroll the complete loop
Kernal elapsed time =      0.031(ms)
Elapsed time =      0.057(ms)
Sum = 8192, with BLC_PER_GRD 8 THR_PER_BLC 1024
#################################################################
7 Final
Kernal elapsed time =      0.015(ms), band =
Elapsed time =      0.040(ms)
Sum = 8192, with BLC_PER_GRD 8 THR_PER_BLC 1024
#################################################################

#################################################################
6 Unroll the complete loop
Kernal elapsed time =      0.569(ms)
Elapsed time =     12.889(ms)
Sum = 8388608, with BLC_PER_GRD 8192 THR_PER_BLC 1024
#################################################################
```

And my gpu:

```
a@M:/usr/local/cuda/samples/bin/x86_64/linux/release$ ./dev*Drv
./deviceQueryDrv Starting...

CUDA Device Query (Driver API) statically linked version
Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 1060 6GB"
  CUDA Driver Version:                           9.2
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 6078 MBytes (6373572608 bytes)
  (10) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     1280 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1709 MHz (1.71 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             4004 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              192-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 1572864 bytes
  Max Texture Dimension Sizes                    1D=(131072) 2D=(131072, 65536) 3D=(16384, 16384, 16384)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(32768), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(32768, 32768), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size (x,y,z):    (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Concurrent kernel execution:                   Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device supports Compute Preemption:            Yes
  Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            Yes
  Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 3 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >
```

Hmm so lets sey that we set 128 threads, grid size as 4:

```
#define MAX_SHM 49152
#define GRID_SIZE MAX_SHM / sizeof(int)

#define THR_PER_BLC 128
#define BLC_PER_GRD GRID_SIZE/THR_PER_BLC
```

Then reduce7 works. So it means that reduce7 depends strictly on max shm?

## Edit

Seems that I was confused by this line: `while (i < n) {`, where n is GRID_SIZE. Then for now I dont know what `i` means. Need to digest it some time. But its good to know, that in one block there can only be specific number of threads, that for this case we had to match with SM.

Comment: regarding your edit, it is a grid-stride loop.  See [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/).  Note that `i` is not used as the index into shared memory in that loop.  It is used as the index into global memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the shared memory needed for this reduction is only as large as the needs of the *block*, not the *grid*.  So asking for shared memory sized to the grid doesn't make sense.

Second, this is asking for 64Kbytes of statically allocated shared memory per block:

```
 __shared__ volatile  int sdata[GRID_SIZE];
```

That can't work, because:

```
Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
```

And, **in addition**, this is asking for 64Kbytes of dynamically allocated shared memory per block:

```
 case 128:
    reduce7<128> << < gsize, threads, GRID_SIZE * sizeof(int) >> > (g_idata, g_odata, GRID_SIZE);
    break;
```

So that combo (64K+64K) would never work.

You seem to be confused about how shared memory is used, and how much is needed per block.  The block only needs one quantity (`int` in this case) per thread.

You may also be confused about [the syntax and usage of statically allocated shared memory vs. dynamically allocated shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066730/allocate-shared-variables-in-cuda).  For this type of problem you would normally use one or the other, not both.

I have no idea what this comment means:

```
 //I added GRID_SIZE myself so it can be volatile
```

Usual suggestion: Any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code, you should be doing [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) and run your code with `cuda-memcheck`, *before* asking others for help.  Even if the example code you start with didn't have proper CUDA error checking, you should **add** it once you start making modifications and running into trouble.

> Then reduce7 works. So it means that reduce7 depends strictly on max shm?

It means that reduce7 needs a certain amount of shared memory per block.  That quantity is one `int` per thread.  That is all it needs.  If you give it more, that is OK (sort of) as long as you don't exceed the maximum that can be given.  If you exceed the maximum that can be given, the whole kernel launch fails.

In other words, all you really need is this:

```
__shared__ volatile  int sdata[THR_PER_BLC];
```

Comment: haha, now its works, thanks, ur ans clarified most of my problems here :D

Comment: hmm, what is method to find optimal blocks per grid and threads per block? i know that in general case its better to use more threads, but on this reduction code? i will try to find it myself, but will spend one week or two to understand this code. ahh i wanted to spend like few days on cuda, two or three :(

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985912/how-do-i-choose-grid-and-block-dimensions-for-cuda-kernels) may be of interest.  You want to be able to use lots of threads in a kernel call, ideally 10,000 or more.

Comment: so in here this specific case we still want more threads than blocks? but SM has to be equal to no of threads here? then we are still limited by thrPerBlc=SM?

Comment: I don't think it's going to be reasonable to try to teach you all the ins and outs of CUDA and GPU behavior in the space of the comments here.  Beginning CUDA programmers should not worry about the number of SMs.  Create lots of threads in your kernel launch, if the algorithm will permit it.  This `reduce7` algorithm as originally written (not your version of it) will work well with a fixed block size, for arbitrary data input sizes.  Study the `reduction` CUDA sample code, and [this](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf).

Comment: [This](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) is the reduction sample code I was referring to.  It is installed with a CUDA toolkit install.