# Correct kernel call in case of using dynamic shared memory allocation

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I didn't find any information about how to allocate static and dynamic shared memory in the same kernel, or lets ask more precisely:

How to call a kernel where the amount of shared memory that needs to be allocated is just partly known at compilation time?

Referring to [allocating shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531247/allocating-shared-memory) for example, it becomes pretty obvious how to do it for dynamic allocation.

But lets assume I have the following kernel:

```
__global__ void MyKernel(int Float4ArrSize, int FloatArrSize)
{
  __shared__ float Arr1[256];
  __shared__ char  Arr2[256];
  extern __shared_ float DynamArr[];
  float4* DynamArr1 = (float4*) DynamArr;
  float* DynamArr = (float*) &DynamArr1[Float4ArrSize];
  
  // do something
}
```

Kernel Launch:

```
int SharedMemorySize = Float4ArrSize + FloatArrSize;
    
SubstractKernel<<< numBlocks, threadsPerBlock, SharedMemorySize, stream>>>(Float4ArrSize, FloatArrSize)
```

I actually wasn't able to figure out how the compiler is linking the size of shared memory only to the part I want to allocate dynamically.
Or does the parameter `SharedMemorySize` represent the total amount of shared memory per block, so I need to calculate in the size of static shared memory (`int SharedMemorySize = Float4ArrSize + FloatArrSize + 256*sizeof(float)+ 256*sizeof(char)`)?

Please enlighten me or just simply point to some code snippets.
Thanks a lot in advance.

cheers greg

Comment: OP! It only expects a single `__shared__` variable. Try to combine everything into a single struct.

Comment: @SorooshBateni no it doesn't! the parameter in the kernel call affects only the size of the dynamically allocated shared memory, the statically allocated parts are unaffected and are fine the way they are.

Comment: Yes I said the dynamic allocating unit (:D) expects only one `__shared__` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citing programing guide, `SharedMemorySize` specifies the number of bytes in shared memory that is dynamically allocated per block for this call in addition to the statically allocated memory; this dynamically allocated memory is used by any of the
variables declared as an external array. `SharedMemorySize` is an optional argument which defaults to 0.

So if I understand what you want to do, it should probably look like

```
extern __shared_ float DynamArr[];
float*  DynamArr1 = DynamArr;
float4* DynamArr2 = (float4*) &DynamArr[DynamArr1_size];
```

Be aware, I didn't test it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531247/allocating-shared-memory) is very useful post.

Comment: Thank you, perfect... now I know how to proceed!

Comment: You are welcome @GregPhil. By the way, the best way to tell somebody thank you at stackoverflow is to up-vote his/her post and also, there is nice habit to accept the most suitable answer, if such exists.

Answer (score 2):

From the [CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#execution-configuration):

> The [kernel's] execution configuration is specified by inserting an expression of
> the form `<<< Dg, Db, Ns, S >>>` between the function name and the
> parenthesized argument list, where:
>
> - [...]
> - `Ns` is of type `size_t` and specifies the number of bytes in shared memory that is dynamically allocated per block for this call **in addition to the statically allocated memory**; this dynamically allocated memory is used by any of the variables declared as an external array as mentioned in [`__shared__`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared); `Ns` is an optional argument which defaults to 0;

So basically, the shared memory size that you specify during the kernel call is related to the dynamically allocated shared memory. You don't have to manually add the size of your statically allocated arrays in shared memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted to know!