# dynamic allocation of arrays in shared memory with different lengths

Tags: cuda

I have to allocate 2 arrays in shared memory at run time with different lengths like this:

```
__global__ kernel()
{
__shared__ int A[blockDim.x*6]; 
__shared__ int B[8][blockDim.x*3];
}
```

How can I ensure that while launching this kernel like `kernel <<<b,t,s>>>` both will take the different lengths?

Comment: The code you have shown is illegal and wouldn't even compile. Could you show us a real, compilable example of what you are asking about?

Comment: Your edit still doesn't make the code legal. `blockDim` can't be used in the way you are trying. CUDA supports dynamic shared memory allocation (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5531640/681865)) but not in the way you are trying to do it

Comment: I know this is not compilable. unfortunately i dont know a way I can achieve what i want.

Comment: What i need is I need to set size of 1D array A to be blockDim.x*6 and width of 2D array B to be blockDim.x*3 whose length is fixed (8). The 3rd parameter in <<<b,d,s>>> applies to all the arrays declared with extern __static__. But i need to set 2 different values to be sizes of 2 different arrays(one 1D and one 2D).

Comment: Please add what you are wanting to do as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 3):

If block size is constant you can declare it as a constant and use it for static allocation:

```
const int BLOCK_DIM_X = 512;
__global__ kernel()
{
    __shared__ int A[BLOCK_DIM_X*6]; 
    __shared__ int B[8][BLOCK_DIM_X*3];
}
kernel<<<grid, BLOCK_DIM_X>>>();
```

If it is not a constant you can use dynamic shared memory allocation:

```
__global__ kernel()
{
    extern __shared__ int smem[];
    int* A = smem;
    int* B = A + blockDim.x*6;
    // B[i][j] will be
    int t = B[i * (blockDim.x*3) + j];
}
size_t smem_size = (block.x*6 + 8 * block.x*3) * sizeof(int);
kernel<<<grid, block, smem_size>>>();
```

Comment: shouldn't `size_t smem_size = (blockDim.x*6 + 8 * blockDim.x*3) * sizeof(int);` be `size_t smem_size = (block.x*6 + 8 * block.x*3) * sizeof(int);`?