# declaring the size of shared memory in cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

My code looks like this (the size of the shared memory depends on other parameters; i.e. not constant for all problems) in CUDA C/C++:

```
__global__ void dist(){
     int a=4; int b=2;
     const int d=a+b;
    __shared__ short unsigned int shared_nodes[a];
}
```

The program does not work and shows the error message:

```
error: constant value is not known.
```

Do you have any idea how can I solve the problem?

Comment: you could always have the shared memory size be passed in as a template parameter. If templates aren't what you're looking for, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531247/allocating-shared-memory/5531640#5531640

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dynamic allocate the size of shared memory, just declare the shared memory first, and give the size when launching:

```
extern __shared__ char array[];
__global__ void shared_memory_1(float* result, int shared_size)
{
    float* sh_data = (float*)array; 
    float* sh_data2 = (float*)&sh_data[shared_size]; 
    ...
}
```

just like the picture discribed:
[image]