# Passing a Constant Integer in a CUDA Kernel

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I am having a problem with the following code. In the global kernel, loop_d, M has an integer value of 84. When I try to create a shared array, temp, and use M as the size of the array, I get the following error:

error: expression must have a constant value

I am not sure why that is. I know that if I declare M as a global variable, then it works, but the problem is that I get the value of M by calling the function d_two in a different Fortran program, so I am not sure how to get around that. I know that if I replace temp[M] with temp[84], then my program runs perfectly, but that is not very practical, since different problems might have different values of M. Thank you for your help!

The program

```
// Parallelized 2D Three-Point Guassian Quadrature Numerical Integration Method
// The following program is part of two linked programs, Integral_2D_Cuda.f. 
// This is a CUDA kernel that could be called in the Integral_2D_Cuda.f Fortran code to compute
// the integral of a given 2D-function
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
// The following is a definition for the atomicAddd function that is called in the loop_d kernel
// This is needed because the "regular" atomicAdd function only works for floats and integers
__device__ double atomicAddd(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_ull = (unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;
    do {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed,
            __double_as_longlong(val + __longlong_as_double(assumed)));
    } while (assumed != old);
    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}
// GPU kernel that computes the function of interest. This is good for a two dimensional problem.
__global__ void loop_d(double *a_sx, double *b_swx, double *c_sy, double *d_swy, double *e_ans0, int N, int M)
{
    // Declaring a shared array that threads of the same block have access to
    __shared__ double temp[M];
    int idxX = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; // Thread indices responsible for the swx and sx arrays
    int idxY = threadIdx.y;     // Thread indices responsible for the swy and sy arrays
    // Computing the multiplication of elements
    if (idxX < N && idxY < M)
    {
        temp[idxY] = a_sx[idxX] * b_swx[idxX] * c_sy[idxY] * d_swy[idxY];
    }
    // synchronizing all threads before summing all the mupltiplied elements int he temp array
    __syncthreads();
    // Allowing the 0th thread of y to do the summation of the multiplied elements in the temp array of one block 
    if (0 == idxY)
    {
        double sum = 0.00;
        for(int k = 0; k < M; k++)
        {
            sum = sum + temp[k];
        }
        // Adding the result of this instance of calculation to the final answer, ans0
        atomicAddd(e_ans0, sum);
    }
}
extern "C" void d_two_(double *sx, double *swx, int *nptx, double *sy, double *swy, int *npty, double *ans0)
{
    // Assigning GPU pointers
    double *sx_d, *swx_d;
    int N = *nptx;
    double *sy_d, *swy_d;
    int M = *npty;
    double *ans0_d;
    dim3 threadsPerBlock(1,M); // Creating a two dimesional block with 1 thread in the x dimesion and M threads in the y dimesion
    dim3 numBlocks(N); // specifying the number of blocks to use of dimesion 1xM
    // Allocating GPU Memory
    cudaMalloc( (void **)&sx_d, sizeof(double) * N);
    cudaMalloc( (void **)&swx_d, sizeof(double) * N);
    cudaMalloc( (void **)&sy_d, sizeof(double) * M);
    cudaMalloc( (void **)&swy_d, sizeof(double) * M);
    cudaMalloc( (void **)&ans0_d, sizeof(double) );
    // Copying information fromm CPU to GPU
    cudaMemcpy( sx_d, sx, sizeof(double) * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( swx_d, swx, sizeof(double) * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( sy_d, sy, sizeof(double) * M, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( swy_d, swy, sizeof(double) * M, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( ans0_d, ans0, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    // Calling the function on the GPU
    loop_d<<< numBlocks, threadsPerBlock >>>(sx_d, swx_d, sy_d, swy_d, ans0_d, N, M);
    // Copying from GPU to CPU
    cudaMemcpy( ans0, ans0_d, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
    // freeing GPU memory
    cudaFree(sx_d);
    cudaFree(swx_d);
    cudaFree(sy_d);
    cudaFree(swy_d);
    cudaFree(ans0_d);
    return;
}
```

Comment: statically allocated shared memory must have a compile-time constant for the size of the static allocation.  In your case, `M` is not known at compile time, so the solution is to use *dynamically* allocated shared memory.  There are many examples of this [here on the CUDA tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5531640/1695960), as well as in the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared). dynamically allocated shared memory uses the `extern` keyword.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: You or talonmies always beat me to the first comment/answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler needs `M` to be a *compile-time* constant. At compile time it cannot determine what `M` is actually going to be (it doesn't know you will just pass it 84 eventually).

When you want to use shared memory of size you only know at runtime, you use *dynamic* shared memory.

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5531640/1593077) here on the site or [Using Shared Memory in CUDA](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/) on the Parallel4All blog.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Using Shared Memory in CUDA link helped a lot!

Comment: @Bassa: You're welcome. But I'll give you the same advice I was given so many times: Before asking a question here it's a good idea to go over the relevant section of the [CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html) first.